# Protecting an object exchange in a multithreading environment

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I've written a Provider/Consumer class that I'm trying to make robust again concurrency.

My question is about the exchange of Value. 
I would to validate my approach. My feeling is that is a not too bad approach **if and only if the class Value is immutable**, right ?

If the class Value were not to be immutable, should it contain itself some lock mechanisms ?

```
class ModuleProvider implements Module {
    Value value = Value.UNSET;

    private final ReentrantLock computeLock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final ReadWriteLock valueLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    public void compute() {
        if (computeLock.tryLock()) {
            // Do some heavy computation

            valueLock.writeLock().lock();
            value = xyz; 
            valueLock.writeLock().unlock();
            computeLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    // Is this the correct way? 
    public Value getValue() {
        valueLock.readLock().lock();
        Value local = value;
        valueLock.readLock().unlock();
        return local;
    }
}

class ModuleConsumer implements Module {
    Value value = Value.UNSET;

    private final ReentrantLock computeLock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final ReadWriteLock valueLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    Module provider;

    public void compute() {
        if (computeLock.tryLock()) {
            Value v = provider.getValue();
            valueLock.writeLock().lock();
            value = Value.from(v); 
            valueLock.writeLock().unlock();
            computeLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public Value getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void exportTo(PriorityBlockingQueue<Message> queue) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I’ve fixed a couple typos in your code because they appear irrelevant to your question. Check out the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54672410/revisions) if you’re curious what changed.

Comment: written with notepad ;) Thanks for the edit